# Why do NVME-read-command and dd have different results?

Tags: ssd, dd, nvme

Why do NVME-read-command and dd have different results?

```
sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p1 of=lba.0.dd bs=4096 count=1
results: abcdefaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa....
```

```
sudo nvme read /dev/nvme0n1p1 --start-block=0 --block-count=0 --data-size=4096 --data=lba.0.nvme
results:\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\.......
```

Comment: I didn't even know the nvme tool, and installed it just now. After playing around a bit and looking at `man nvme-read` I also don't understand what's happening. Would definitely be interested in what we're doing wrong :)

Comment: What happens if you use the device `/dev/nvme0n1` on both commands instead?

Comment: Interesting, there I get the same output, 'nvme read' prints much less than 'dd' though.